# deleting record from oracle database using entity framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I would like to delete a record using the entity framework. DB is oracle.

Approach 1:

```
public void DeleteTask(Guid taskId, string userId)
{
    var task = _context.TWFITSKs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == taskId.ToString());//<---Error line
    if (task == null) return;
    _context.TWFITSKs.Attach(task);
    _context.TWFITSKs.Remove(task);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

> Error : ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

`TWFITSK` does contain a column with datatype as `CLOB`, but not sure why that is causing a problem in this select statement.

Approach 2:

```
public void DeleteTask(Guid taskId, string userId)
{
    var task = new TWFITSK { ID = taskId.ToString() };
    _context.TWFITSKs.Attach(task); // <--- Error line
    _context.TWFITSKs.Remove(task);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attaching an entity of type
>   'XXXXX.TWFITSK' failed because another entity of the same type already
>   has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the
>   'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.
>   This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received
>   database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or
>   the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of
>   non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'

Approach 3:

```
public void DeleteTask(Guid taskId, string userId)
{
    var task = new TWFITSK { ID = taskId.ToString() };
    _context.TWFITSKs.Remove(task); //<--- Error line
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

> Error: The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager

Comment: In your approach 1 you should get rid of the Attach call since you are getting it from the context so no need to attach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing the entity state to deleted:

```
var task = new TWFITSK { ID = taskId.ToString() };
_context.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Deleted;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

**Update**: try passing the entity to your method as it sounds like its already attached to the context.  This may work:

```
public void DeleteTask(TWFITSKs task)
{
    if (task == null) return;

    _context.TWFITSKs.Remove(task);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: @Shaggy it must already be attached to the context. my update may work, if you can pass the entity to the method

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call `.Remove`

```
var task = new TWFITSK { ID = taskId.ToString() };
_context.TWFITSKs.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Deleted;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

but this may still won't work if you have datatype mismatch. It may be better If you can share table **DDL script**, **class definition** and **OnModelCreating**

Comment: Error :  `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.'`

Comment: since you are instantiating new TWFITSK without using context, ObjectStateManager cannot track it. Try above approach

Comment: then please share DDL script of your table, class definition and OnModelCreating part of your context.